# Transferring old partition info to the new hard drive for Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I just bought a new hard drive to replace the 20GB hard drive in the Halo 3 Edition system. I want to use it in the detachable shell on the top of the system, but I'm having problems getting the old partition info from the old drive to the new one.

Can anyone give me some instructions on how this is done?

Comment: Do you have a transfer cable?

Comment: Do you have a flash drive?  You should be able to transfer over data that way (even if it means switching the hard drive out a few times)

Comment: There are ways to partition laptop drives to become Xbox 360 HDD's. Although this, would possibly be under modifying the Xbox periphials(controllers,cables,HDD's). So, I'm pretty sure it can't be answered here.

Comment: @Brok3n by definition, configuring a 3rd-party HDD to work with an Xbox is not modifying Xbox components, it's modifying non-Xbox components.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a program called Horizon to copy the info to a usb thumb drive and then to your new drive if you have access to a second sata connection on your computer. you would have to dismantle the old harddrive as well...which I believe required a security torx driver (maybe t6?). This program saved my hindside seriously when I had a faulty sandisk card switch to read only and microsoft had no solution and suggested my data was permanently destroyed...the program recognized all saved games and save files and I was able to copy them all despite some having copy protections...good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to format the hdd on the xbox in the settings -> storage tab. If you want to transfer data I think you have to use a transfer cable.

Comment: So I could format it with the xbox storage tab and transfer all of my hard drive info over that way? I bought an enclosure for the hard drive. I want to use the new one for the primary. will this way enable me to do that? or do i have to put a special partition on the drive?

Comment: @ZachGolden did you buy an official Xbox hard drive, or a standard PC hard drive? The latter will only work via USB, and that has a max size of 32GB.

Comment: I believe I heard they increased external drive max capacity to 2tb finally, but the original 360 does have a secure code that runs inside the drives and so only certain hdds can be reprogrammed to be usable inside a 360 google "upgrade phat 360 hdd" and you should find a list of compatible drives and programs that work if you are in fact talking of an attempt to change the sata drive inside a 360/enclosure.